# How to auto-increment characters in spring boot / oracle

Tags: angular, spring, oracle, spring-boot, lombok

I would like to generate a code "AAA" for a specific product. And the next entry would be "AAB".
And goes on till "AAZ". Once "AAZ" is over the newly generated key would be "ABA" and so on.

```
AAA         ABA
AAB         ABB
AAC         ABC
AAD         ABD
AAE         ABE
.           .
.           .
.           .
AAZ        ABZ
```

The above table is an example that I need. How can I do it in spring boot?
I'm using spring-boot as backend technology, Angular for the frontend, and oracle for the database.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, from version 12, use an `IDENTITY` column to generate sequential numbers and then use a virtual column to create the character sequence from the number:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id     NUMBER(5,0)
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 17575)
         PRIMARY KEY,
  str_id CHAR(3)
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
           CAST(
             CHR(65+TRUNC(id/POWER(26, 2)))
             || CHR(65+MOD(TRUNC(id/POWER(26, 1)), 26))
             || CHR(65+MOD(id, 26))
             AS CHAR(3)
           )
         )
)
```

However, you would probably be better to just use the underlying numeric column and then generate the string value in the front-end when you want to **display** the value.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3a700a5c0484a1aae03c39cca53aae5c)*